# formatting read data from txt file

Tags: c, format

The purpose of this program is to read a file and format it with 62 characters per line. This program compiles and partially works, most of the lines are 62 chars or less, however some of the lines are actually 64 chars.

I was wondering how I get it to print 62 chars or less for ALL  the lines?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE

void output(char *wbuf, char *lbuf);
void readFile(FILE *getty, char *wbuf, char *lbuf);

FILE *getty;
static int lineLength = 62;
int main(void) {
char wbuf[1000] = {0}, lbuf[1500] = {0};

if (fopen_s(&getty,"getty.txt", "r") != 0 )
    printf("Failed to open getty.txt for reading.");
else {
    readFile(getty, wbuf, lbuf);
}

fclose(getty);
return 0;
}

void readFile(FILE *getty, char *wbuf, char *lbuf) {
int count = 0;


while (!feof(getty) ) {
    if (fscanf(getty, "%s", wbuf) > 0) {
        strcat(wbuf," ");
        output(wbuf, lbuf);


    }
}
printf("%s\n",lbuf);
}

void output(char *wbuf, char *lbuf) {

int wbufLength=0, lbufLength, i = 0;


wbufLength = strlen(wbuf);
lbufLength = strlen(lbuf);

if ( (wbufLength + lbufLength) <= lineLength) {
    strcat(lbuf,wbuf);

}
else {
    strcat(lbuf,"\n");
    lineLength += 62;
    strcat(lbuf, wbuf);

}
}
```

output:
Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth,    //58 chars
upon this continent, a new nation, conceived in liberty, and 
dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal. Now  // 64 chars
we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that 
nation, or any nation, so conceived, and so dedicated, can long 
endure. We are met here on a great battlefield of that war. 
We have come to dedicate a portion of it as a final resting 
place for those who here gave their lives that that nation 
might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should 
do this. But in a larger sense we can not dedicate - we can 
not consecrate - we can not hallow this ground. The brave men, 
living and dead, who struggled here, have consecrated it far 
above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little 
note, nor long remember, what we say here, but can never 
forget what they did here. It is for us, the living, rather to 
be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they have, thus 
far, so nobly carried on. It is rather for us to be here 
dedicated to the great task remaining before us that from these 
honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for 
which they here gave the last full measure of devotion - that we 
here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in 
vain; that this nation shall have a new birth of freedom; and 
that this government of the people, by the people, for the 
people, shall not perish from the earth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you addjust the *lineLength* variable.

```
lineLength += 62;
```

By adding 62 to the *lineLength*, you're assuming that you've used up 62 characters in your *lbuf*, but that isn't the case. You'll typically have used up less, because the number of words that fit in 62 characters will typically end up being fewer than 62 characters. As a result, all subsequent calculations are going to be slightly off.

What you should be setting the new *lineLength* value with is this:

```
lineLength  = strlen(lbuf) + 62;
```

Also note that this isn't a perfect algorithm because you're adding a space onto each word before checking if it fits. This means that a word that would just fit exactly in the 62 character limit ends up being wrapped because the space pushes it over the limit. I don't know whether that is a problem for you or not.